# What set of build sounds do you use?

Tags: audio, build

Applications like CCTray allow one to specify a sound clip to indicate that a build is successful or that a build failed. I'm interested to hear what set of sounds different teams are using.

Here are two sets that we use:

- Homer Simpson: "d'oh" for a build failure, "woohoo!" for success
- Mario bros: power down sound for a build failure, power up for a build success, 1-up for a build fixed

Comment: You put sounds in? Man I build thousands of times a day! I would go insane..

Comment: You don't need CCtray to do this. Visual Studio installs events in the system sound control that you can then assign to sounds.

Comment: "The Build" on one of my projects (up to 3 EARs for different environments) can take a few minutes to run, so I look forward to hearing a ding when it finishes (or doesn't finish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

South Park:

- "Oh my God, they've killed Kenny!" for a build failure.
- "Kickass!" (Cartman) for a success.

Answer (score 3):

I produce a soft groaning sound for a build fail.

Answer (score 2):

For build failures: Tom Hanks from Apollo 13, "Houston, we have a problem."

Answer (score 2):

- Successful Build: [Mario gets a coin!](http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/sounds/super_mario_bros_nes_sounds.php)
- Failed build: either [DUN-dun-dun](http://www.freesound.org/samplesViewSingle.php?id=45654) or [Sad Trombone](http://www.freesound.org/samplesViewSingle.php?id=73581) (I haven't quite decided yet).

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of the Microsoft C/C++ compilers, I've used sounds from the pinball game that came with Windows XP and the Windows 95 Plus! pack. I used sounds that the game used for successful actions for successful build events; and I used sounds that the game used for failure events (like losing the ball) I used for build failure or warning events. I also used pinball sounds for events like hitting a breakpoint in the debugger. Sadly, the latest versions of MS Visual Studio don't expose nearly as many events to the Sounds control panel anymore. :-(

Answer (score 1):

And your co-workers appreciate your computer producing the same sounds over and over again? A gazillion times a week? Man, I can't even play music in here without getting complaints.

Comment: hehe - good point. Maybe only have a sound for the build breaking? That would really make it just that little bit more painful to break the build :)

Comment: `That's why they make headphones.